# Amazon Kindle Fire and .apk file

Tags: android, apk

I am currently trying to install an .apk file onto Amazon Kindle Fire android..
I tried the normal method, which is downloading the .apk file from the email straight from it, but it couldn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, downloading from email and installing works for me. Can you specify the error message?

Comment: Hi, I will check and get back to you on that..

Comment: Hi, the error states "The is a problem parsing the package"..

Comment: OK. I've encountered this kind of bugs as well, even from Google Market. Try to re-send the email with your APK file.

Comment: Just resend the email with the .apk file again?

Comment: hmm.. the Error still persists...

Comment: OK, then try to do this in Eclipse: Project -> Clean... -> OK. Then export your app again, and re-send the Email.

Comment: But the problem is, I can install the same .apk file on other android phones, only kindle having this problem

Comment: I'm making some Android apps to. There is one case, that after I sent my APK file to a user, he told me it cannot be installed, having the same bug as yours. But my apps works on all the machines except his.

Comment: Can I ask, If my kindle's version is 6.2, is it still possible to install an application which is version 2.3?

Comment: It's possible. Kindle is running Android 2.3 (though the kindle's version is different).

Comment: How do I find out the android version on my kindle?

Comment: You don't need to find. It cannot be others, because Android 2.3 is the only version that built kindle software built on. You can find it in Settings -> About

Comment: Is kindle able to install apps outside of amazon app store though?

Comment: Of course, it's possible. I've been doing this for many times.

Comment: Alright thanks for all the comments. However, still can't get any of my self developed apps to work on my kindle. going crazy!

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is called `sideload`ing. Before doing that you would need to go to Fire's:

```
"Settings" => "+ More" => "Device"
```

and enable

```
"Allow Installation of Applications"
```

[image]

Then you can just open you APK from the e-mail client and installed with pretty much any file manager.

[ES File Manager](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004HN2FY0) is commonly used to sideload apps on Fire.

[Here](http://www.extremetech.com/mobile/107555-five-free-kindle-fire-apps-sideload) you can get more details on using Dropbox to push APKs to your Kindle, as well as which browser to use instead of a built in Silky thing.

Comment: Hi, the error still states "The is a problem parsing the package"

Comment: your APK maybe no good. I just sideloaded a [Dolphin Browser HD](http://apkbin.blogspot.com/2011/12/dolphin-browser-hd-720-final-apk.html) ( download APK, send to your email, open email from your Kindle Fire's browser, click on APK ), on Kindle Fire using above steps.

Comment: I cant even install ES File Manager.. even when the app is free, I am told to enter my credit-card number (?!)

Comment: are you saying you can't install _any_ even Amazon apps? If that is the case, you would probably want to either root your Fire or call Amazon. As a side note, you don't really need "ES File Manager" to sideload apps => sending APK to you email and accessing it from Kindle works as well.

Answer (score 2):

I found a work around using some of the mentioned things above. I was getting the same error for every apk that I sent to my Fire via email. Here was my workaround:

1. Go to 'Settings' > 'More' > 'Device'
2. Make sure that you have selected **ALLOW Installation of Applications** to **ON**
3. Go to the Amazon App store and download a file manager app like [ES File Manager](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004HN2FY0). This program is free via the Amazon App Store. **Don't** send this to your device via email. Install it via the 'apps' > 'store' menu on your Fire.
4. Email yourself your APK files.
5. Click 'save' on your attachments
6. Open your file manager (ES File Manager) and open your downloads folder.
7. Click on the app file to install (and it works).

Sounds too easy, but I was getting the same error when trying to install by opening the email attachment. This worked for me.

Comment: Okay will give that a try once I get my US credit card. Thank you so much!

Comment: @BB_Developer You probably figured out a workaround for your "problem parsing the package" error, but the reason I submitted this workaround was because I was getting the same error and the above solution fixed it. The sideloading problem for me came from trying to open the packages without saving them first. This is why you need the ES File Manager. Installing from there after saving seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just got my own Kindle Fire now and had to find the solution on my own (my problem is that I cannot download anything at all from Amazon Store, as I do not have a US card or US billing address). If I am using the native Kindle Fire mail app and try to open the attachment, I get an error "There is a problem parsing the package".

However, if I access Gmail through browser and download the app, it opens and installs just fine.

Hope that helps